# What is the C++ equivalent for "//" operator (floor division operator of Python) in C++?

Tags: python, c++, operators, bitwise-operators

In Python, we have floor division operator `//`.
Is there any similar operator in C++?

---

Edit 1: In C++, Int Division is always floored but integer division rounds toward 0 instead of Flooring. So, to handle all data limitations what should be an ideal function in C++?

---

Comment: What are your operand types?

Comment: Integer division works like this by default in C++, so that would just be `/`. Are you asking for some other datatype than `int`?

Comment: [std::floor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor)

Comment: @SampurnAnand integer division is always floored.

Comment: Note that C++ integer division rounds toward 0, rather than flooring. If you want floor behavior, you'll need manual handling for negative numbers.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: The result of `-1//2` is `-1` in Python, but `-1/2` is `0` in C++.